# Make a node package both CLI and JavaScript functional

Tags: node.js, node-modules

How do you make a node packaged that has both a CLI and JavaScript API where the specific logic is exicuted based on where it is run.

This is obviously very similar to most major node packages however I have not been able to find any discussions on this kind of pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a shebang line at the beginning of any JavaScript file, for example consider this file, *hello.js*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

function hello(name) {
    console.log('hello ' + name);
}

/* if called directly from command line or from a shell script */
if (require.main === module) {
    hello(process.argv[2]);
}

module.exports = hello;
```

Note the first line that tells your shell how to execute the code.

You can make *hello.js* executable with this command:

```
chmod u+x hello.js
```

Now you can invoke it like this:

```
./hello.js joe
```

It will output: "hello joe".

You can also use the same file as a dependency in any other JavaScript file in Node.js as usual:

```
const hello = require('./hello');
hello('joe');
```